# Pad String with zero in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, pad

I have a log file with a date, ie:

```
LOG_20120509_100000.log
(year) (month) (day) _ (hour) (minute) (second)
```

But imagine that i want to perform the same thing on a set of hourly log files. I want to be able to do this:

```
for i in 0:23
    perform on LOG_20120509_%d0000.log, i
end
```

But this wont work for the logs with hours of less then 10 oclock because it will become:

```
LOG_20120509_50000.log
```

So how can i pad out the zeroes in matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `%d` usage suggests that you are using `sprintf` or similar to generate the filenames, in that case it would suffice to use `%02d` for zero padding the hours.